# Dividing the integers in two separate arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

What I am trying to do is when given two arrays:
{1,5,1,7}, 
{4,1}

I want to get {3,7}. BTW, 1517 / 41 = 37

I can't think of simple algorithm to accomplish this. I can't simply convert the arrays into integers and use the regular division operator, because numbers in the arrays could be very huge that integers can't hold.

I've heard that using long division can help, but when I read it on Wikipedia, it only explains how to do math (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division). I know how to divide two numbers.

If you were to write some code, I'd prefer c++, but doesn't matter.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Long division is essentially the **algorithm** for dividing two numbers expressed as sequences of digits.  It's exactly what you need.  (Alternatively, defer to a big-integer library.)

Comment: Building off @OliCharlesworth 's comment: If you're trying to program your own division function as an exercise, then the long division algorithm is exactly what you need, and it would be very good practice for you to come up with your own implementation of the algorithm from scratch. If you just need large-integer division in order to make something work, then don't bother rewriting libraries that already exist.

Comment: This question has already been in the StackOverflow. Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322129/array-division-what-is-the-best-way-to-divide-two-numbers-stored-in-an-array

Comment: I feel dumb. Could you explain in more detail how to use long division? To me, it seems like a simple math that I already know. That's not exactly an algorithm, it's just elementary math. I don't see how this could help...

Comment: @Nayana: Look at the animation on the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Example_with_multi-digit_divisor); that's the algorithm running in front of your eyes ;)

Comment: @Nayana: it is *exactly* an algorithm -- a set of rules/instructions that describe a finite sequence of steps that solves the problem. The fact that you know it doesn't mean it's not an algorithm ;-) If you can't program long division then probably the issue is that you "know how to do it" but you don't have in mind a sufficiently precise description of the steps you carry out when you do it. Usually the fix for this is to do a few by hand and take careful note of what you actually do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python, this is easy.

```
f = lambda L: int(''.join(map(str,L)))
a = [1,5,1,7]
b = [4,1]
print map(int,str(f(a) / f(b))) # [3, 7]
```

Comment: But the OP is using C++.

Comment: _If you were to write some code, I'd prefer c++, but doesn't matter._

Comment: This ignores "I can't simply convert the arrays into integers and use the regular division operator, because numbers in the arrays could be very huge that integers can't hold."

Comment: @Stefan Python doesn't care how big an integer is.  It implicitly takes care of it.

Comment: @CodyPiersall: actually, in python 3 the max size and accuracy will be limited by what floats your system can handle. It won't be perfect for very large numbers.

Comment: @KillianDS: Good point!  It took me a minute to realize what you were meaning.  I was thinking about integer division, in which case the size of the numbers doesn't matter.

Comment: Integer division is `//`, so it's a simple fix :-) But I suspect that embedding Python in the questioner's program isn't a useful solution. What this answer amounts to is saying, "there exists a programming language where the problem you have is already solved out of the box".